# Clear Duplicates in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates

I searched Stack Overflow for this kind of problem. But I found several similar problems regarding this one, but show different solution.

I would like to display data in my datagridview without duplicates. I don't know how did it duplicated.

```
conn.Open();
            query = "SELECT Books.BookID,Books.Title,Books.AuthorID,Authors.AuthorName,Books.ISBN from Books,Authors";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
            while (dr.Read())               
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
               dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString());
            }
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
```

What I want to happen:

> BookID | BookTitle | etc..
>
> 100001 | Sociology | etc..
> 100002 | History   | etc..

And this is the datagrid that shows everytime

> BookID | BookTitle | etc..
>
> 100001 | Sociology | etc..
> 100002 | History   | etc..
> 100001 | Sociology | etc..
> 100002 | History   | etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to fetch `DISTINCT` records from database and then bind them to `datagridview`

```
 query = "SELECT DISTINCT Books.BookID,Books.Title,Books.AuthorID,Authors.AuthorName,
          Books.ISBN from Books,Authors";
```

Note:
 This query will make row distinct if there is any column has different value. So it's upto you that which column's value you want to be distinct and would like to display on grid.

one more thing, Use `JOIN` instead of Cartesian product if possible like this

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT Books.BookID,Books.Title,Books.AuthorID,Authors.AuthorName,
         Books.ISBN from Books 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Authors on Books.AuthorId=Author.AuthorId";
```

EDIT: Try this for binding

```
using(SqlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
     {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
     }
```

Comment: It's still showing duplicates. Actually, my database doesn't have duplicated values. I do not know when I fetch them from Database to the DataGridView, it becomes duplicated.

Comment: @AkoSiAsiong change `SqlReader` to `SqlDataReader`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
conn.Open();
query = "SELECT Books.BookID,Books.Title,Books.AuthorID,Authors.AuthorName,Books.ISBN from Books,Authors";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

dataGridView1.Clear();

da.Fill(dataGridView1);

cmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
```

Not sure if this is entirely correct but it may help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your query to use DISTINCT, as this will remove duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Books.BookID,Books.Title,Books.AuthorID,Authors.AuthorName,Books.ISBN from Books,Authors
```